# how to display app name in place of "ios" during facebook sharing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I am using this code the sharing happens but it shows ios as the application.How can it display my application name ?

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender
{
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your app on Facebook for that and have to share through Facebook SDk ( not Social framework).

Facebook sdk tutorial is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/)

Comment: you should check..i think share kit latest source will do it using social framework only on iOS 6.. learning the Facebook way will be the best since share kit includes multiple social network and editing its source will become extra complicated